# Fallback for Javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display an animated Javascript presentation on my homepage but I would like to fallback to just displaying some text and images if javascript is disabled.

Is placing the fallback content within the `<noscript>` tags sufficient for this?

Comment: you can use `noscript` tags and put your image, text with proper styling if needed. That will be rendered when js is disabled

Comment: If Javascript is `enabled` in the browser, does the content within `noscript` tags still get downloaded?

Comment: it will be present in the DOM I believe but won't reflect anything to the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `noscript` tags and put your image, text with proper styling if needed. That will be rendered when js is disabled.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/noscript.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also skip the `<noscript>` tags and put your text and images in a normal div on the page.  Then use JS to replace that content with your animated presentation.